# URL in String resource xml

Tags: android, string, url, encoding, resources

I have stored a couple of urls in `strings.xml` file. I want to store them without encoding them (as raw text), but `strings.xml` throws error for `=` and `&`.

For example:

```
http://www.example.org/index.php?p=616687&ac=some_q
```

If I store the link as it is, it will throw the error:

```
The reference to entity "ac" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

However, if I replace the `&` with `%26`:

```
http://www.example.org/index.php?p=616687%26ac=some_q
```

while this works without any error, this doesn't open the correct page in the browser.

Is there any way I can store the links in `strings.xml` as it is without formatting or uri encoding them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `&` directly, because XML document is expected to be [well-formed](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#sec-well-forme) and the problem is with `&` character itself. For XML/HTML you would have to use `&amp;` entity (or `&#38;`), but for URL use [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and replace `&` it with `%26` (as you did) which should simply work as browsers do understand such things as they simply have to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I came up with a workaround, since I am not sure why the website was loading a different page. I used regex to replace `%26` with `&` when retrieving the url from `strings.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You could Base64 encode and decode your URL Strings with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html